# Unable to build openssl in Xcode 4.2.1

Tags: ios, xcode, openssl, xcode4.2, gcc4

I could build openssl in xcode 3.5.2, but recently I upgraded to Xcode 4.2.1. Now when I try to build in the same old Xcode, I'm getting errors.

Make[1]: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory

```
Cp: libcrypto.a: No such file or directory
Cp: libssl.a: No such file or directory
```

Can I have a solution for this?

Comment: did you set the "Header Search Paths" for the static library?

Comment: No i haven't, but the error is with GCC 4.2.. how can we resolve this

Comment: try adding $(SRCROOT) to Header Search Paths. Also check the  recursive tick box.

Comment: Hi Vin where do i find recursive tick box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for XCode 4. You need to change in "Build Phases" the text `$PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR/gcc-4.2` to `$PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR/gcc`. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Chadwick,javbaezga, can u be a bit brief, coz even changing to gcc from gcc-4.2, Im getting same error?